# add text to random textarea in html (php)

Tags: php, html

I would like to know if something like this is possible for php:

Very-Pseudo-Code:

```
<body>
    <textarea name="text1">
</body>

<?php
   $A=mysqli_connect(...);
   if($A){**text1.echo "Connection established";**}

   $B=mysqli_select_database(...);
   if($B){**text1.echo "Database selected";**}
?>
```

I want a life feedback that tells the user what is going on in the background. Kind of a life feed that consistently gives the user information. I played around with GET and POST methods and also with PHP_SELF, but nothing worked out. 
In javascript it seems to be quite simple with something like

```
    document.myform.append()
```

Is there something like this for php, or do i have to mix it with javascript?
(This is my first html/php project, i hope its not a silly question)

Comment: What you are Looking for is known as AJAX.

Comment: The server outputs HTML only after all the PHP is executed, so directly it's impossible. You could check out Server Sent Events though

Comment: @MikołajRozwadowski please refrain from linking to w3schools.

Comment: Sorry, that was the first page with a decent description that I found